# merge two forms fields in drupal

Tags: php, forms, drupal

I am merging the form with another form contains table based. Table contains the list with checkbox, after filling the form fields, checkboxes are selected and submitted.

When i write this code, Two forms with same id is generated how should i merge the two functions in one form.

```
function add_newHardware() {
        $output = drupal_get_form('add_new_form');
  return $output;
}

function add_new_form(&$form_state) {

 $form['#attributes']['id'] = 'myform';
  $form['device'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['device']['type'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => listType(),

  );


 $form['device']['title'] = array(
'#type' => 'item',
      '#value' => '<h4>2. Enter Information</h4>',


  );
  $form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#value' => drupal_get_form('selectList'),
  ); 
}

function selectList() {
 $form['#attributes']['id'] = 'myform';
...... 
$output .= theme('table', $header, $rows);
 $output .= drupal_render($form);

 return $output;
}
```

Comment: You can merge any number of forms as long as their keys don't overlap by calling the other form function in the first function. If you return the $form array in selectlist(), and if you call selectlist() in add_new_form(), the form output will have both forms. If you want to have multiple selctlist() calls, make sure you pass some argument to that function so you can change keys.. 
Not sure I understood you question correct though.

Comment: I got ur answer. where do i pass the $key value?

Comment: to the selectlist() function.. So if you pass "1" here, you can force the selectlist() function to use this argument in keys for FORM ELEMENTS. i.e. input tags, text areas, etc. So they will not mess up with existing form elements. Also, do not use this key in form attributes such as redirect, id, classes, form encoding type, etc.